# Бинарный поиск с счётчиком

Tags: c++

Дают число n и нужно вывести сколько таких чисел в массиве, используя бинарный поиск.

Например число 4
Массив 1 2 4 4 4 2 4 1 4
Ответ 5

Comment: Эм.. Вообще-то так не работает.

Comment: а как можно сделать за logn ?

Comment: Ну вообще-то бинарный поиск только на отсортированных массивах работает

Comment: ну допустим отсортирован

Comment: Ну тогда проблема в чем ? upper_bound - lower_bound сделать?

Comment: и это для всех дупликатов ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если массив отсортировать, то `std::equal_range` сделает именно то, что вам надо

```
int a[] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 };
auto range = std::equal_range(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 4);
std::cout << range.second - range.first << std::endl;
```

На самом деле `std::equal_range` не требует строгой сортированности входного массива. Ей достаточно лишь, чтобы массив был partitioned по искомому значению.

Однако если вы возьметесь делать `std::partition`, то оно вам и так даст требуемый диапазон без полной сортировки массива

```
 int a[] = { 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4 };
 auto lo = std::partition(std::begin(a), std::end(a), [](int i) { return i < 4; });
 auto hi = std::partition(lo, std::end(a), [](int i) { return i < 5; });
 std::cout << hi - lo << std::endl;
```

Хотя все это имеет смысл только потому, что условие без объяснения причин настаивает на использовании какого-то "бинарного поиска".

Comment: спасибо,сейчас попробую !

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы за логарифмическое время искать повторяющиеся элементы в массиве, можно использовать [`std::multiset<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
  int a[] = {1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4};
  std::multiset<int> S {std::begin(a), std::end(a)};
  std::cout << S.count(4) << std::endl;
}
```

Элементы хранятся в отсортированном порядке. Временна́я сложность `S.count()` логарифмическая по длине массива и линейная по количеству найденных совпадений (элементов эквивалентных (`!(a<b) and !(b<a)`) заданному ключу).

Если каждый раз новый массив задаётся, то лучше чем `O(n)` нельзя поиск сделать:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int a[] = {1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4};
  std::cout << std::count(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 4) << std::endl;
}
```